# Analysis of the differentiability of a multivariable piecewise function. (verification)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

$$ 
f(x,y)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             \frac{e^{-|x-y|}}{1+|x-y|} &   ,  & x\neq y \\
             \\ \hspace{0.6cm} 1 &  , & x = y  \\
             \end{array}
   \right.
$$
$f$ is rewritten as follow
$$
f(x,y)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             \frac{e^{-x+y}}{1+x-y} &   ,  & x>y \\
             \\ \frac{e^{x-y}}{1-x+y}  &  , & x<y \\
             \\ \hspace{0.5cm}1  &  , & x=y \\
             \end{array}
   \right.
$$
For $x-y>0 \iff x>y$

$$ \lim_{ (x,y) \to (y,y) } \frac{e^{-x+y}}{1+x-y} = 1 $$

For $x-y<0 \iff x<y$
$$ \lim_{ (x,y) \to (y,y) } \frac{e^{x-y}}{1-x+y} = 1 $$

Then $f$ is continuos at the points $x=y$.

$$ 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             -\frac{e^{\left(-x + y\right)}}{x - y + 1} - \frac{e^{\left(-x + y\right)}}{{\left(x - y + 1\right)}^{2}} &   ,  & x>y \\
             \\ -\frac{e^{\left(x - y\right)}}{x - y - 1} + \frac{e^{\left(x - y\right)}}{{\left(x - y - 1\right)}^{2}}  &  , & x<y \\
             \\ \hspace{1.6cm} 0 &  , & x=y \\
             \end{array}
   \right.
$$

$$ 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             \frac{e^{\left(-x + y\right)}}{x - y + 1} + \frac{e^{\left(-x + y\right)}}{{\left(x - y + 1\right)}^{2}} &   ,  & x>y \\
             \\ \frac{e^{\left(x - y\right)}}{x - y - 1} - \frac{e^{\left(x - y\right)}}{{\left(x - y - 1\right)}^{2}}  &  , & x<y \\
             \\ \hspace{1.6cm} 0 &  , & x=y \\
             \end{array}
   \right.
$$

If $ x>y $
$$ \lim_{ (x,y) \to (y,y) } \nabla f(x,y) = ( -2,2 ) $$
If $ x<y $
$$ \lim_{ (x,y) \to (y,y) } \nabla f(x,y) = ( 2,-2 ) $$

But $ \nabla f(y,y) = (0,0) $ . Then $\nabla f(x,y)$ is not continuous at the points $x=y$.

Is $f$ differentiable at $(0,0)$?

For $x>y$
$$ \lim_{ (x,y) \to (0,0) } \frac{ f(x,y) - f(0,0) - \langle \nabla f(0,0) , (x,y) \rangle }{ ||(x,y)|| } = \lim_{ (x,y) \to (0,0) } \frac{ f(x,y) - 1 }{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} } $$
$$ = \lim_{ (x,y) \to (0,0) } \frac{ \frac{e^{-x+y}}{1+x-y} -1 }{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \lim_{ (x,y) \to (0,0) } \frac{\frac{ e^{ -x+y } -x+y-1 }{x-y+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{ e^{ -x+y } -x+y-1 }{ \sqrt{x^2+y^2} (x-y+1)} $$

Using polar coordinates

$$ \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{ e^{ r(-cos\theta + sin\theta)} + r( -cos\theta + sin\theta )  -1  }{r^2(cos\theta - sin\theta) +r} \overbrace{=}^{L'hopital} $$

$$ \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{ ( -cos\theta + sin\theta )e^{ r(-cos\theta + sin\theta)} - cos\theta + sin\theta  }{ 2r( cos\theta - sin\theta )  + 1} = -2cos\theta + 2 sin\theta \neq 0 $$

Analogously for $x<y$
$$ \lim_{ r \to 0 } \frac{ ( cos\theta - sin\theta )e^{ r(cos\theta - sin\theta)} + cos\theta - sin\theta  }{ 2r(sin\theta - cos\theta) +1 }  = 2cos\theta - 2sin\theta \neq 0 $$

Hence $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Is this analysis correct?

Comment: For the last part, you could have used the previous result, about $\nabla f$, and choose $y=0$